# Is it possible to have a field named `NameSpace__c__c`

Tags: custom-field, platform-bug

I've been having a somewhat strange issue here when trying to create a custom field.

With the following deployment, I ended up with a field that looks like it's missing the ending `__c`:

```
<fields><fullName>c__c</fullName><externalId>false</externalId><label>c__c</label><length>255</length><required>false</required><trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory><trackHistory>false</trackHistory><trackTrending>false</trackTrending><type>Text</type><unique>false</unique></fields>
<fields><fullName>xc__c</fullName><externalId>false</externalId><label>c__c</label><length>255</length><required>false</required><trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory><trackHistory>false</trackHistory><trackTrending>false</trackTrending><type>Text</type><unique>false</unique></fields>
```

[image]

Attempts to access `c__c` in Apex code results in the deployment error:

> The configuration of your org has changed, please reload the page. Missing dependent object: Field: c123cn__Log__c.c123cn__c

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I would like to use just `c` as the base field name if it is possible.

Comment: Sounds like +1 to my internal phobias list -- creating package with name that ends with letter C